# Jmeter Timer at EOF?

Tags: timer, jmeter, performance-testing, eof, data-files

Does anyone know if its possible to add a timer within a test which only runs when a datafile reaches EOF?

i.e. multiple threads running through a test, accessing 1 data file. When the file reaches the end, before looping back to the beginning, it waits 5 minutes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) with "Recycle on EOF = True" there is no way to detect the "last" line of data as you will not get `<EOF>` value of the variable.

I can only think of adding an [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage) and use the following [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) as the condition:

```
${__groovy(new File('/path/to/your/file.csv').readLines().size() == (vars.get('__jm__' + ctx.getThreadGroup().getName() + '__idx') as int) + 1 ,)}
```

Then add a [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler as a child of this If Controller and configure it to wait for 5 minutes:

[image]